# HSQLDB clear table data after restart

Tags: hsqldb, temporary, in-memory-database

I want to save some temporary data in memory, which should be removed after server shuts down.

There is a temporary table in HSQLDB, but the data is removed immediately after transaction committed, which is too short for me. On the other side, the memory table keeps a script log file and resume the data when server new starts. It takes time and place to maintain such script logs, which are useless for my situation.

what I need is just a type of table, only the table structure is persistent in hard disk, the data and the data operations should only be performed in memory. Otherwise why do I need a in-memory DB instead of mysql?

Is there such type of table in HSQLDB?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the file: database, then create the tables. Perform SHUTDOWN. Edit the .properties file for the database, add the setting below and save.

```
files_readonly=true
```

When you perform your tests with this database, no data is written to disk.

Alternatively, with the latest versions of HSQLDB 2.2.x, you can can specify this property on the connection URL during the tests. For example

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:myfilepath;files_readonly=true
```

Comment: thanks, but I cannot change data after that. what I need is only keep the table schema persistent, the data inside table could be updated in runtime, but won't be stored in hard disk.

Comment: You are not setting the `readonly=true` property which prevents any change. The suggested property allows you to add and modify data without writing to disk.

Comment: thanks, you are right, the readonly and files_readonly are totally different. I tested, it works! What I should do is building the table structure in common mode like before and then change the files_readonly property to true, it's just like a snapshot, all states at that point will be restored automatically when server new starts. Thank you very much

Comment: Added alternative for using the property.

Comment: thanks, I'm using jboss 6.1, which contains a hsqldb 1.8 out-of-box. Anyway thanks alot for your advice, I think jboss7 maybe contain a new version.